# Based on month value match with ISODate

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Suppose I have data stored as:

```
const apple = {details:[{"someDate" : ISODate("2021-01-16T06:42:52.652Z")},
                        {"someDate" : ISODate("2021-03-16T06:42:52.652Z")}]}
```

Suppose I receive in the req.body value as 1 and I want to match the value with date ISODate
if 1 exists as a month in ISODate perform some action.

Like.

```
for(let i=0;i<apple.details.length;i++){
    if(apple.details[i] == match month with iso date){
        console.log('this month exists here and perform the action')
     }
}
```

So basically I want to check if the month exists in the date stored and if it does move forward.

I tried looking for solution but was unable to find anything for it.

Answer (score 1):

[ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates are strings with a standard formatting. To pick only the month, you could get a part from the string, like

```
// 2021-01-16T06:42:52.652Z
//      ^^
month = ISODate.slice(5, 7); // '01'
```

and compare it with the wanted month with padding for zero.

```js
const
    apple = { details: [{ someDate: "2021-01-16T06:42:52.652Z" }, { someDate: "2021-03-16T06:42:52.652Z" }] },
    month = '03';

for (const object of apple.details) {
    if (object.someDate.slice(5, 7) === month) {
        console.log(object);
        console.log('this month exists here and perform the action');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added my solution...please let me know whether it is more feasible or not?

Answer (score 0):

```
const apple = { details: [{ someDate: "2021-01-16T06:42:52.652Z" }, 
                          { someDate: "2021-03-1 6T06:42:52.652Z" }] }
```

say in a body we receive month as 1

```
for(let i=0;i<apple.details.length;i++){
    if(apple.details[i].receivedOn.getMonth()+1 == 1){
        console.log('this month exists here and perform the action')
     }
}
```

So basically it extracts month from ISODate and matches with body value .

Comment: where is `getMonth` coming from?

Comment: it's predefined function in nodeJs......as with the date I just applied this function and it extracted the month from the date.